# Ubuntu dock's "Show Applications" button is missing in Ubuntu 20.04 on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with GNOME. I just installed it on VirtualBox a couple hours ago and didn't install any app. On the bottom-left corner of the screen there is no '*Show Applications*' button.
[image: missingbutton]

I'm searching for a while but I only found guides to move the button or change its icon etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is that you have set an incorrect screen resolution and that's why the whole bottom part of the screen is getting truncated. In that case change the screen resolution to a suitable one.

Otherwise, if the '*Show Applications*' button accidentally got *disabled* somehow, then running the following command in Terminal should bring it back:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-show-apps-button true
```

Comment: I saw your comment and set my resolution from 1080p to 720p and yes all the time the bottom part of my screen was getting cut off. Thank you for your help